# Fresh install has missing icons

Tags: theme

Spun up a fresh install of Civi 5.64.1 on Drupal 9.5.10. Everything is running well but the icons are just little square boxes. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: missing icons]

Comment: Check http vs https in all your configs - this is usually some mismatch, e.g. civicrm_base_url in civicrm.settings.php

Comment: Thank you for the tip. It turned out to be that $settings['trusted_host_patterns'] in the settings.php had only '^www\.srccrm\.com$', when it needed to be an array with '^srccrm\.com$', also.

Comment: update, I also had to edit the civicrm.settings.php file and change https://srccrm.com to https://www.srccrm.com. Now the icons are showing.